# jetty or pfdreactor throws endless warning message oeji.nio:Dispatched Failed

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, pdf-reactor

We use pdfreactor (a html to pdf tool), recently we start to see the error file keep on growing (goes to 80gb until there is no space). There is some warning message which I posted here. My experience is on .net side so for a java web server, I don't really know what to do and where to look.

There is a previous stackoverflow question, but I don't think there is an answer I can use.

I contacted pdfreactor support, but ideally wants to see if anyone else got this issue and maybe someone point me to the right direction?

```
2015-09-07 05:44:02.126:WARN:oejs.AbstractConnector:Acceptors should be <=2*availableProcessors: SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9423
2015-09-07 05:44:02.251:WARN:oejd.WebAppDeployer:WebAppDeployer is deprecated. Use WebAppProvider
2015-09-07 05:44:02.266:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.15.v20140411
2015-09-07 05:44:02.313:INFO:oejs.NCSARequestLog:Opened C:\Program Files\PDFreactor\jetty\logs\2015_09_07.request.log
2015-09-07 05:44:02.438:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/PDFreactor/jetty/webapps/imgdemo.war!/ to C:\Users\SERVICE_PDFR_LIV\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-9423-imgdemo.war-_imgdemo-any-\webapp
2015-09-07 05:44:16.817:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/PDFreactor/jetty/webapps/pdfreactor.war!/ to C:\Users\SERVICE_PDFR_LIV\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-9423-pdfreactor.war-_pdfreactor-any-\webapp
2015-09-07 05:44:18.349:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9423

2015-09-07 06:43:41.525:WARN:oeji.nio:Dispatched Failed! SCEP@1274dfe9{l(/10.11.11.36:45923)<->r(/10.11.11.206:9423),s=-1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0}-{AsyncHttpConnection@37184376,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} to org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager@19f5143c
2015-09-07 06:43:41.525:WARN:oeji.nio:Dispatched Failed! SCEP@1274dfe9{l(/10.11.11.36:45923)<->r(/10.11.11.206:9423),s=-1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@37184376,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} to org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager@19f5143c
2015-09-07 06:43:41.541:WARN:oeji.nio:Dispatched Failed! SCEP@1274dfe9{l(/10.11.11.36:45923)<->r(/10.11.11.206:9423),s=-1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@37184376,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} to org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager@19f5143c
2015-09-07 06:43:41.541:WARN:oeji.nio:Dispatched Failed! SCEP@1274dfe9{l(/10.11.11.36:45923)<->r(/10.11.11.206:9423),s=-1,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=1r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@37184376,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} to org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager@19f5143c
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues.

- [Jetty 8.x is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) - this is *the most important issue* you have.
- The warning `Acceptors should be <=2*availableProcessors` means you have misconfigured your acceptor count
- The warning `WebAppDeployer is deprecated. Use WebAppProvider` means you are using deprecated functionality from the Jetty 6.x days (removed in Jetty 9.x btw)
- The warnings about `oeji.nio:Dispatched Failed! SCEP` are typically seen from either a bad ThreadPool configuration, or a faulty JVM.  In both scenarios the needed NIO processing isn't being given the resources it needs to handle the request/response exchange.

Comment: Hi Joakim, This config is provided by the software vendor and I am not a java developer at all. Do you have any suggestion on what we should set?

Comment: Sorry, nope.  Might want to send the vendor a link to this question/answer.